90s Scifi novel about a small town puppet-masters-style alien invasion with conflicted invader POV
I read a book when I was in Junior High (92-95 timeframe) that involved an alien invasion in a small town with sections from the point of view of the invaders. It was similar to The Puppet Masters in that the invaders themselves were relatively small, even fragile, creatures and they took control of people's bodies. I seem to recall that one of he POV characters was an invader who was conflicted about the invasion and their relationship to their host.  I don't think it was a YA novel, but I can't be certain. I seem to recall a subplot where one of the humans was able to wall off physical pain due to trauma or abuse, and this was helpful somehow. This character may have been the host to the alien POV character.
For some reason, I am remembering the aliens as tiny little brains, but that may be a red herring.
I initially looked at the answers to This Question, but none of them quite seem to fit, and I don't recall all of the human characters being teen-aged, though the human character I mentioned earlier might have been.

Some of this makes me think of The Animorphs though it's a couple of years too late.

Probably not https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/242594/23243 where the invading aliens look human (although they eventually transform if they don't take their "medicine") but mentioning it for the record.

It's definitely not the Animorphs. I remember thinking they looked cheesy with their themed covers and avoided them. This is not a judgement on them now, just to say that I know for a fact I never read any of them. I also have a memory of the cover to this novel being somewhat stark and bleak. Perhaps even a landscape with a lone human figure. I also don't recall this book being part of a series.

The Host is probably a bit too late for your timeframe.

The Host is very similar, but yes, too new.  Also, in my book I seem to recall that the main host character was male. I remember there was another somewhat sympathetic alien controlling a female character and they -ahem- express themselves physically through their hosts and it was deeply strange.
